# Cmake INSTALL command for debug and release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake

I have to execute the following cmake command while building a VS2012 solution.

```
#Install Debug .pdb and .exp files
INSTALL(
    CODE "FILE( GLOB PDB_EXP \"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Debug/*.pdb\" \"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Debug/*.exp\")"
    CODE "FILE( INSTALL \${PDB_EXP} DESTINATION \"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib\")"
)
```

Pdb and exp files are meant for debug mode. However, this command is executed in both debug and release configurations. Can I have separate INSTALL commands for debug and release configurations?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`INSTALL`'s](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html) `CONFIGURATIONS` option:

> `CONFIGURATIONS`
>
> Specify a list of build configurations for which the install rule applies (Debug, Release, etc.).

Note that you need to use `INSTALL(FILE [...])` instead of `INSTALL(CODE [...])` + `FILE` for this purpose. In my experience, this is preferable anyway, as using the install mechanism all the way through tends to be more robust than globbing.

Obtaining the locations of the pdbs without doing the `GLOB` can be a bit fiddly, but you can infer it from the target properties of the targets in the install set.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question: Since CMake 3.14 it is possible to use "generator expressions" with the syntax `$<...>` in [`install(CODE <code>)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#code). This would allow for something like the following:

```
install(
  CODE [[
    if($<CONFIG:Release>)
    ...
    endif()
    if($<CONFIG:Debug>)
    ...
    endif()
  ]]
)
```